# IE9/IE10 chrashes when hiding tablerow with different cell borders

Tags: crash, internet-explorer-9, hide, tablerow

I discovered a Bug in IE9 and IE10 platform preview. My code contains a simple table with a little style, cells in first column have different borders. If I hide the last row with simple javascript, IE crashes.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/ZT6wm/2/

Someone an idea for Workaround?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing and would also love a workaround/fix.

Comment: Have been searching the internet on this one for weeks, it appears MS has been ignoring this problem?

Comment: I have described a solution here: [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12583617/1266313)

Comment: This does not crash the final version of IE10. Tested both on Windows 7 and 8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [tr display none crashes ie9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326697/tr-display-none-crashes-ie9)